# Can we set multiple callbacks with cascade notation using the arrow syntax in Dart?

Tags: dart

Is it possible to use the Cascade notation for setting multiple callbacks with the arrow syntax?

This code here shows an error, as it tries to set `callback2` on `int`, the result of `sum()` and not `MyClass`:

```dart
void main() {
  MyClass mc = MyClass()
    ..callback1 = () => sum()
    ..callback2 = () => sum() // error here
    ;
}

class MyClass {
  Function callback1;
  Function callback2;
}

int sum() => 2 + 2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is ambiguous to the parser, hence the error. If you wrap the closures in parens, the error goes away:

```dart
void main() {
  MyClass mc = MyClass()
    ..callback1 = (() => sum())
    ..callback2 = (() => sum());
}

class MyClass {
  Function callback1;
  Function callback2;
}

int sum() => 2 + 2;
```

Personally, I'd recommend creating variables for those callbacks and using those to assign to `callback1` and `callback2`. Depending on your use case, it might be even better to pass these callbacks as parameters to a constructor instead.

Comment: Why passing variables instead of closures is better? Just for readability?

Comment: Yeah, just for readability, particularly when you're passing multiple closures like that. It's honestly personal preference, and for one liners like in this example you can get away with it (although you _could_ also just pass `sum` as the callback directly here), but I find it keeps things cleaner as you iterate on your design.

Comment: Oh yes, sure, but I simplified my code here, otherwise I would pass it  directly. Thanks Ben

Comment: That's what I figured (I very much appreciate simplified code snippets :-)), but figured I'd mention it either way. Glad to help!